# Simplifying code for Message box were file name is built from File.WriteAllText

Tags: c#

I have the this code that I would like to simplify

```
       File.WriteAllText(
            Path.Combine(dir,
                DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + "-" + messageType + "-" + messageGateway + ".csv"),
            messageBody);

        MessageBox.Show(Strings.AllActionLogViewModel_ExportMessageContentToCsv_Saved_Log_File + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + "-" + messageType + "-" + messageGateway + " " + "to " + dir);}
```

As you can see I have duplicated the filename syntax in MessageBox.  I would like to condense this so my message box returns the file name but gets it from the File.WriteAllTest method as opposed to rewriting the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it to a variable and then reuse it where needed. This will also avoid a potential problem where your `DateTime.Now` is used in two different spots. While not likely, it is possible that you could get two different values between the two calls in the event the second changes.

I would also make use the [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to make it a bit more readable:

```
var fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",
    DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"),
    messageType, messageGateway);

File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, fileName + ".csv"), messageBody);

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} {1} to {2}",
    Strings.AllActionLogViewModel_ExportMessageContentToCsv_Saved_Log_File,
    fileName, dir));
```